Is this likely to be asbestos under my floor?
I've seen some dents forming in the floor of my cellar, probably due to moisture. I opened a dent in one place and removed some of the floor to examine it. The floor should have been built in 1980 in West Germany.
I discovered this white material and immediately thought of asbestos. Does anyone have an idea if my guess is probable or not? Or does anyone have an idea what kind of floor this is with this white layer?
Here is a short video where you can see fibers shimmer in the light.



1980 it is a possibility.  It will need testing for proof, no one can/will tell from pictures.  Nothing to worry about if using a good mask/eye protection if sanding/removing it.  Quite safe if it is covered over.

What's the flooring? It looks like inlaid sheet vinyl. Is the fibrous layer attached to it or separate?

it is not asbestos, it looks like fiberglass/mineral wool
